# What exactly is meant by, "Postdocs are free agents, they are not livestock"?

Tags: interpretation

In some answer to a question, regarding the stressful life the asker is having in his research environment, somebody wrote in the line of, "Postdocs are free agents, they are not livestock".

As I understand so far, perhaps he wanted to mean that postdocs have the liberty of moving from one research facility to another if the circumstances are not in his favor. Postdocs are not simply  "domesticated animals raised in an agricultural setting to produce commodities such as food, fiber, and labor".

Is my understanding correct? Perhaps you would like to supplement a bit more to make the idea clearer.

Comment: You understanding of the quotation is correct. However, one of the things your dictionary  told you is that _livestock_ is an _uncountable noun_. Do you know what an _uncountable noun_ is, and how it differs from a _countable_ noun? Click on the **[edited](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/136775/revisions)** link to see the changes that were made.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Since that was a quote, perhaps it would have been more appropriate to append "*sic*" instead.

Comment: @Masroor The contrast was possibly along the lines of a protest because they wanted to pursue their own research directions instead of just being part of the 'herd' of postdocs doing the department's systematised research program. However, you're better off asking the relevant postdoc directly.

Comment: @Lawrence Since the OP evidently consulted a dictionary (from which he reproduced a definition) he must also have seen the notation _uncountable_ on the same page; yet no mention of this is included in the question, although it is arguably more important (and certainly more elementary) than understanding the figure of speech about postdocs.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Then why do Oxford, Cambridge and Longman dictionaries write the example sentences without the 's'? Please see, https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/livestock. Click on `More example sentences`.  You get 20+ examples. Also, please see, http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/livestock. Please see, http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/livestock.

Comment: You posted the question with a quotation which includes the word _livestock**s**_.The dictionary tells you that _livestock_ is an _uncountable_ noun. Do you understand what is wrong with the way you spell this noun in your question? Do you understand what an uncountable noun is?

Comment: @P.E.Dant Yes, I *do* understand what an uncountable noun is. My point is, as the edit history shows, my original question was with that `s`, which was a mistake from my part, you corrected it in the first revision, which I welcome. But then, an hour later,  in the next revision, you put back that 's', thus making the question identical with my *original* erroneous question. That puzzled me.

Comment: @Masroor I rolled back my edit to be sure you recognized the error, since you didn't mention it in your question.. Do you understand why an uncountable noun cannot have a plural form?

Comment: @P.E.Dant Yes, I definitely do. I already explained what puzzled me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct in inferring the meaning. Post-docs are people that have agency to change jobs, they are not owned by their institution.